# ¿Como generar una contraseña del largo seleccionado en un input range?

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando una app para generar contraseñas aleatorias.

Necesito leer el valor que el usuario eligió en un input range y usarlo como argumento de una funcion, para generar una contraseña con el largo de ese valor.

La pregunta sería ¿como hago para generar la contraseña con el valor del input?.

Este es el código que he escrito y hasta donde he llegado con mi lógica.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector("#input-range");
const output = document.querySelector("#output-el");

function passwordLength() {
  output.innerHTML = `Number of characters:  ${slider.value}`;
  console.log(slider.value);

  return Array(4)
    .fill(0)
    .flatMap(() => [
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)],
      numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)],
      symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)],
    ])
    .join("");
};

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  input1.value = passwordLength();
  input2.value = passwordLength();
  input3.value = passwordLength();
  input4.value = passwordLength();
});
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <p class="sub-title">Select the length of your password</p>

  <input id="input-range" type="range" min="4" max="12" value="4" onchange="passwordLength(value)" />
  <p id="output-el">Number of characters:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perdón. La pregunta sería como hago para generar la contraseña con el valor del input.

Comment: Se lo que genera mi codigo. 
El problema es que no se como generar una contraseña con el largo que figura en el input.value

Comment: Como pasar ese valor a la funcion? Lo tengo que pasar a la funcion como argumento? Lo tengo que pasar dentro del Array() ? si es asi de que manera? Ya que he intentado y no supe como

Comment: No Marcos. Como voy a tomar para mal una ayuda. 
Solo que no entiendo bien donde y de que manera aplicar la lógica para que el largo de la contraseña cambie según el número seleccionado en el input.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Marcos gracias a esta pista que me diste lo pude resolver. Simplemente al join("") le uni el subString(0, slider.value) y con eso lo pude resolver. 
Espero que me hayas entendido si no paso todo el codigo.

Comment: Me pone muy contento que hayas podido resolver tu problema por tus propios medios. Podes responder a tu propia pregunta y así contribuir con la solución, y porque no, ganar puntos. Mi consejo, agrega una respuesta con tú código.

Comment: Gracias Marcos!

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la ayuda de un integrante de este grupo @Marcos he podido resolver mi problema.

Problema: Como generar una contraseña con el largo que el usuario eliga desde un input range?

Solución: Concatenar el método subString(0, input.value) al metodo join("") al final de la función passwordLength().

El método subString() extrae del string devuelto por el meotodo join(), que en este caso es un string con 12 caracteres, los caracteres situados entre los dos argumentos. En este caso iniciamos la extracción desde el índice 0 hasta el valor del input. (Valor seleccionado por el usuario)

```
const slider = document.querySelector("#input-range");
const output = document.querySelector("#output-el");

function passwordLength() {
  output.innerHTML = `Number of characters:  ${slider.value}`;
  console.log(slider.value);

  return Array(4)
    .fill(0)
    .flatMap(() => [
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)],
      numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)],
      symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)],
    ])
    .join("").**substring(0,slider.value)**;
};

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  input1.value = passwordLength();
  input2.value = passwordLength();
  input3.value = passwordLength();
  input4.value = passwordLength();
});
```